# What causes "Template is not defined" in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

This extremely simple Meteor app is throwing a `Template is not defined` error on load.  The app is essentially identical to the boilerplate project (`meteor create`), just split into server/client/public directories.

Meteor seems to be trying to render the Handlebars `template` tags before the global Template object is actually ready.  By the time I can get to the JS console and type "Template", it is there.

Have I done something wrong, or is this a timing bug?

Comment: Where are you including this template for use? It sounds like you're trying to include the template before first loading meteor.js

Comment: Meteor handles bundling and including all js files in your project, so it isn't possible to include the template before meteor.js.  If I'm understanding you right.  Either way, the selected answer shows what the problem was.

Comment: I got this issue when I switched `UI.registerHelper` to the new `Template.registerHelper`. It must be that the deprecated `UI` used to be defined for both server and client but `Template` is defined for only client.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm, perhaps this will solve your issue:

Note that the body tag includes the template name but not the template:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{greet}}
</template>
```

Also, note that ".greet" refers to {{greet}}:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greet = function () {
    return "Hey!";
  };
}
```

So, the issue was that you can't have a template inside the body.  Instead, the body calls the template with {{> hello}} as in the above code.

Comment: It is now `Meteor.isClient` and not `is_client`

Answer (score 27):

You need to make sure in your .js file which calls the Template is wrapped in `if (Meteor.isClient){}`, otherwise the `Template` global var won't be available for some reason.

Comment: Why this behaviour? Do I need this trick even if I use different client/server folders?

Comment: I was in same position separate folders for client and server. After I did this, the error went away. But I'm not 100% sure whether this is the appropriate solution. You shouldn't need to do this. Maybe my meteor server died and I was not aware that the browser caches and it looks like the app still runs.

Comment: This is what happened to me, forgot to add `, "client"` in `api.addFiles()` in `package.js`.

Answer (score 5):

If this in a package make sure you have templating in your api use list ie

api.use('templating', 'client');

That ensures your code is run once the Template object is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Try Template.hello.this to pass the data to {{this}}

Answer (score 0):

This is an initialisation problem. I am using Meteor 1.0 and I solved the problem by adding
`Meteor.startup(function () {}` or an `if` block to `Meteor.isClient`.

This may be a bug, because the documentation on special directories says as below (as of today):

> Client: Any directory named client is not loaded on the server. Similar to wrapping your code in if (Meteor.isClient) { ... }. All files loaded on the client are automatically concatenated and minified when in production mode. In development mode, each file is sent individually for easier debugging. HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level elements: `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<template>`. The head and body sections are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on initial page load.

But without initialisation, this fails with a "Template not found error".