# Why does a new app give 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined' error

Tags: meteor

So these are the steps I followed -

- Create a new meteor app using: `meteor create myapp`

A vanilla app is created with a css, html and js file.

- Start the app using the `meteor` command.
- Simply edit the `<title>` text in `myapp.html`

The page
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined`.

I've gone through [What causes “Template is not defined” in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442419/what-causes-template-is-not-defined-in-meteor) but, unlike there, even the directories have been left untouched.

This has been happening since a recent update to 0.3.6

There cannot be anything I am doing wrong, am I? Well there's nothing really being done to go wrong. I am really not doing anything except changing the title in html.

Also, one last thing I even tried stripping down to the basic HTML without CSS or JS. As shown in the screencast. And this time obviously there is no error since Template is not being used, but the page refreshes into an empty page.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Please show us your adjusted html file on a site like https://gist.github.com/.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2802217

I've tried this on Firefox 13.0 and Chrome 19.0.1084.46 on openSUSE 12.1 Linux kernel 3.1.10-1.9-desktop

Comment: Looks like there is some issue on my PC. I tried meteor out on a Mac and things are fine. Will have to figure it out.

Comment: I am still unable to figure out. Any help would be appreciated. I ran updates for Chrome and Firefox. I now get  [these errors](http://pastebin.com/fsttUmKB). Does this have anything to do with node.js conflicts?

Comment: Looks like this issue is still open. But it works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm seeing the same issue.  See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/168.